# Upgraded to 4.6 Civicrm javascript errors Error can't send email or press some buttons

Tags: civimail, joomla, javascript

Error: b.indexOf is not a function b@https://www.websiteremoved.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js

I can't add receipients or get past step one of generating a draft, firebug reveals a constant error of:

: b.indexOf is not a function b@https://www.websiteremoved.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js

It is literally this article from the old forums but I cannot seeem to find any solutions at all Please help! Its Christmas!!!

forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36343.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the new Civicrm introduced a new pretty template with lots of popups and other cool web features, turn it off and return to the classic gui interface and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

issues.civicrm.org is down right now - but I see this issue: [CRM-12570](http://java-prod.civicrm.osuosl.org:9080/jira/browse/CRM-12570) "Javascript error when mootools is loaded in Joomla backend".  I'll also note that everyone reporting this problem is using Joomla.  So my guess is that there's a Joomla plugin that's causing a jQuery conflict or similar.

To troubleshoot this, I would:

- Disable all your other Joomla plugins.  I hope you're doing your upgrade on a dev server before doing it on a live server!  If disabling all of them solves the problem, start turning them back on until you can identify which one has the conflict.
- Check your Net tab in your browser's developer tools when loading a page on your site vs. on the [demo Joomla site](http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/).  Are there any errors, or unusual JavaScript files on your live site compared to the demo?  If so, identify their source.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I actually already disabled all plugins in Joomla except the 3 core civicrm ones and same issue, I did notice that  this file was in the net tab of the demo site and NOT listed in the net tab of my site http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js

Answer (score -1):

I'm having this issue as well, but I'm on a Drupal site.  I don't have anything extra installed, just the core of drupal and a very basic Civicrm.  No extenstions, no plugins.  In drupal, there's only one other mod an that's webforms.  Everything is updated.

I can't seem to fix this!